# Deleting matplotlib plot /tkinter canvas from window

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, canvas, plot

I was wondering how you can completely delete a plot from a tkinter window.

Assuming i would have a tkinter project like the following:

```
import tkinter as tk
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

data1 = {'Country': ['US','CA','GER','UK','FR'],
         'GDP_Per_Capita': [45000,42000,52000,49000,47000]
        }
df1 = DataFrame(data1,columns=['Country','GDP_Per_Capita'])


root= tk.Tk() 
  
figure1 = plt.Figure(figsize=(6,5), dpi=100)
ax1 = figure1.add_subplot(111)
bar1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure1, root)
bar1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)
df1 = df1[['Country','GDP_Per_Capita']].groupby('Country').sum()
df1.plot(kind='bar', legend=True, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('Country Vs. GDP Per Capita')

def close_plot():
    plt.close(figure1)


button_delete = Button(root, text='Delete', command = lambda: close_plot()).place(height=30, width = 100, rely=0.02, relx = 0.4)


root.mainloop()
```

I veen trying to use matplotlib.pyplot.close within a button but it doens't seem to work.
Anyone have a clue how to get rid of this plot.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your figure is embedded in a `tkinter` widget. You need to keep a reference to that widget, and use its methods to add/remove it from the tkinter window:
Here we use `pack_forget()`: the widget is removed from the window, but still exists, and could be reused later.

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


def remove_plot():
    w.pack_forget()   # here you remove the widget from the tk window
    # w.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # data
    x, y = [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16]

    # matplotlib stuff
    figure1 = plt.Figure(figsize=(6, 5), dpi=100)
    ax1 = figure1.add_subplot(111)
    ax1.plot(x, y)
    ax1.set_title('Country Vs. GDP Per Capita')

    # tkinter stuff
    root = tk.Tk()

    bar1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure1, root)
    w = bar1.get_tk_widget()
    w.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)   # here you insert the widget in the tk window
    button_delete = tk.Button(root, text='Remove Plot', command=remove_plot)
    button_delete.place(height=30, width=100, rely=0.02, relx=0.4)   # place is an odd choice of geometry manager, you will have to adjust it every time the title changes

    root.mainloop()
```

Alternatively, if you don't need that figure any longer, you could use `w.destroy` (commented line) to destroy the widget.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your input! Very helpful.